# Ïndice Repetido

Tags: sql, sql-server, index

espero me puedan ayudar con esta duda que tengo

Tengo una tabla de Operaciones que maneja un campo Fecha, supongamos se hacen varios reportes con filtro por campo Fecha.

En el primer reporte el query al ser analizado con el plan de ejecución solicitará un índice con el campo Fecha y con los includes con los campos solicitados para el reporte en el mismo orden que se solicita.

En el segundo reporte el query de nuevo es análizado y si los campos no son los mismos SQL Server interpreta que el índice creado anteriormente no es viable a usar y solicita crear otro índice con el campo fecha y en el include los campos solicitados en el reporte.

Si creo un tercer  o cuarto reporte donde el filtro es fecha sucede lo mismo no reconoce los índices anteriores a menos que coincidan los campos solicitados en el orden como se metieron en el include.

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo hacer un índice por el campo Fecha donde cualquier query que use ese campo como filtro use ese índice en vez de sugerir crear otro?

Comment: creando otra tabla que guarde las fechas y que estén asociados a un indice de la tabla reportes. un reporte puede tener muchas fechas, todos asociados por el indice.

Comment: Respuesta rápida, el motor hace lo mejor que puede  a la hora de identificar que índices usar en cada consulta, y estas decisiones que toma, son inescrutables. ¿Quieres encontrar un índice que sea útil para la mayoría de los usos de la tabla? pues bienvenido al mundo de l optimización y los DBAs. La configuración de índices es un arte, solo puedes experimentar para encontrar la mejor combinación que apunte a la mayoría de los reportes, o al menos a los más usados y/o más pesados.

Comment: Sino, dependiendo de que versión de SQL Server manejes podrías forzar el uso de ciertos índices mediante un "Index Hint", pero yo no podría muchas fichas en eso, imagino que el motor es el más capacitado para saber que índices usar.

Comment: Agregando a lo que dice @PatricioMoracho, es importante evitar los "Index Hint" lo más posible, ya que en la mayoría de los casos pueden afectar negativamente el rendimiento. Su uso debe ser evaluado por expertos mediante pruebas intensas y que se deben monitorear de forma constante.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el principal medio de acceso a la tabla será por medio de la columna fecha, necesitas que el índice clustered comience por esa columna.

Déjame plantear un poco las bases. En SQL Server hay 2 tipos principales de índices (hay más que por ahora no mencionaré): clustered y non-clustered.

El índice clustered tiene una llave que define su estructura en forma de árbol-b. Este índice no contiene solo la llave sino toda la información de la tabla. De hecho, se puede considerar que el índice clustered es la tabla y por eso solo puede existir uno en cada tabla. Una forma de verlo, es como un diccionario que no tiene las palabras separadas de las definiciones sino que todo está junto y ordenado.

Los índices nonclustered mantienen la estructura de árbol-b pero solo contienen las llaves y un apuntador hacia la ubicación de la fila dentro de la tabla. Esto quiere decir que si una columna no está en la llave del índice, tiene que ir a consultar la tabla para obtener la información. Eso es una operación costosa y por eso se agregaron las columnas incluidas. Estas columnas no forman parte de la llave del índice, por lo que no se puede buscar por medio de ellas, pero se encuentran en "las hojas" del árbol para reducir el espacio de almacenamiento necesario y tenerlas disponibles al usar ese índice.

Si como mencionas, es muy común que las filas se consulten por fecha, pero dependiendo del reporte las columnas incluidas pueden variar. Es ideal usar la fecha para el índice clustered en vez de ir creando múltiples índices nonclustered o agregar demasiadas columnas incluidas que estarían duplicando información.

Por último, es importante mencionar que las sugerencias de índices que realiza SQL Server siempre serán de índices nonclustered porque se asume que ya existe un índice clustered o se decidió que no hubiera.